# uwsgi cannot find Flask application: (callable not found or import error)

Tags: python, deployment, flask, wsgi, uwsgi

I am roughly following this [deployment guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) for Flask. When I launch my app through uwsgi, I receive the error:

> *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
>
> unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
>
> *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***

It is the same issue as this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030809/flask-and-uwsgi-unable-to-load-app-0-mountpoint-callable-not-found-or-im), so it is a python path problem, but I still can't get my app to run. Here is my setup:

```
/home/btw/prod/
.... app.py
.... inits.py
.... templates/
.... wsgi.py
.... prod.ini
.... env/       <--- virtualenv dir
```

**inits.py**

```
# This initializes everything

from flask import Flask
#... other imports

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = False

# Flask-Migrate
migrate = Migrate(app,db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```

**app.py**

```
# This holds the main application code and routes 

from inits import *

@app.route('/doit')
def doit():
    return render_template('doit.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

**prod.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

socket = prod.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

**prod.conf (used to start the flask app):**

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve prod"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid btw
setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/btw/prod/env/bin
chdir /home/btw/prod
exec uwsgi --ini prod.ini
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from app import manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

I also tried doing:

```
from prod import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

But this complains about `ImportError: No module named prod`.

Can someone help me out with why uwsgi can't find my application?

**EDIT**:

I think I found the problem, but I dont know what the solution is. Calling `manager.run()` causes the application to not be found, but if I just use `app.run()` instead, bypassing Flask's manager, uwsgi successfully locates the application.

Why is that?

Comment: have you tried `module = wsgi:manager`?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so after a few hours of exploring this mess, I figured it out!

When running uwsgi, `app` must be conflicting with some other internal module. I've changed my initialization to be `application = Flask(__name__)` and did `from app import application`. Now my application is being loaded correctly.

Comment: No, it's because by default `uwsgi` loads `application` not `app`.  https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#deploying-flask